# "Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked Aborted" when using waitKey

Tags: python, opencv3.0, imshow

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie installed. I'm trying to display an image using `cv2.imshow`, which works. I see it very briefly. However when I try the following code to leave the image up for 2 seconds:

```
 cv2.waitKey(2000)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following error:

```
Attempt to unlock mutex that was not locked
Aborted
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

I was using

```
cv2.startWindowThread()
```

Prior to waitKey. When I removed this it worked.

Matt

Comment: It took literally 4 minutes to figure it out yourself, probably less then the time you spent writing the question. However, glad you make it work. Mark this as an answer.